# VBA Excel Run-time error '1004' on changes to cells outside of Named Range

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, multi-select

Use case: I need to implement a multi-select dropdown based on a named range. I define that named range across multipe worksheets. I thought that the code below only executes when working in cells that are using the "Fruits". However, whenever I try to make changes to any cell on any page I receive the following error:

Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
Debugger opens at line 10 and when I hover over target it has whatever text I am adding to a cell which is not part of the "Fruits" range.

```
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("HVA_Range")) Is Nothing Then
```

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim OldVal As String
    Dim NewVal As String

    ' If more than 1 cell is being changed
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("Fruits")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Turn off events so our changes don't trigger this event again
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        NewVal = Target.Value
        
        ' If there's nothing to undo this will cause an error
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Undo
        On Error GoTo 0
        OldVal = Target.Value
        
        ' If selection is already in the cell we want to remove it
        If InStr(OldVal, NewVal) Then
            'If there's a comma in the cell, there's more than one word in the cell
            If InStr(OldVal, ",") Then
                If InStr(OldVal, ", " & NewVal) Then
                    Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, ", " & NewVal, "")
                Else
                    Target.Value = Replace(OldVal, NewVal & ", ", "")
                End If
            Else
                ' If we get to here the selection was the only thing in the cell
                Target.Value = ""
            End If
        Else
            If OldVal = "" Then
                Target.Value = NewVal
            Else
                ' Delete cell contents
                If NewVal = "" Then
                    Target.Value = NewVal
                Else
                    ' This IF prevents the same value appearing in the cell multiple times
                    ' If you are happy to have the same value multiple times remove this IF
                    If InStr(Target.Value, NewVal) = 0 Then
                        Target.Value = OldVal & ", " & NewVal
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

It seems to work fine, when I use make changes in the Fruits named range.

Comment: I ran into this when attempting to debug your previous question... and now can't repro it, except on a sheet that doesn't contain the named range.

Comment: I have the same result, I didn't notice it only happened on pages without the named range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have observed, this error will occur when processing a sheet that does not have the named range.

You will need to detect the absence of the Name, and abort

Add this before the `If Not Intersect ...` line

```vb
Dim nm as Name
On Error Resume Next
Set nm = Sh.Names("Fruits")
On Error GoTo 0
If nm Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

---

There are a number of other issues/opertunities in this code that could be addressed

1. Trap the error is the sheet that changes is not a worksheet
2. If more than one cell changes, rather than exit handle each cell
3. Allow User to enter several comma seperated item, handle each one
4. Allow user to leave out or enter several spaces after a comma.  Leave multiple spaces in a term as is.
5. I've used `TextJoin` to rebuild the delimited list.  If your version of Excel doesn't support that, it can be done another way (see commented out alternative)

I've included an `UpdateCell` sub that defines the rules to update a cell.  If my interpretation doesn't match yours, let me know.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim OldValue As Variant
    Dim NewValue As Variant
    Dim rChanged As Range
    Dim TargetArea As Range
    Dim TargetAreaVal As Range
    Dim a As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim NamedRange As String
    
    NamedRange = "Fruits" ' change to suit your needs
    
    ' Check for Changes we don't want to process
    '   Sh is not a Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = Sh
        If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    '   No Named range on sheet
        Set nm = ws.Names(NamedRange)
        If nm Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Use handler to ensure Events are turned back on
    On Error GoTo EH
    Set rChanged = Application.Intersect(Target, nm.RefersToRange)

    If Not rChanged Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ' Use Jagged Arrays to allow for non-contiguous ranges
        ReDim NewValue(1 To Target.Areas.Count)
        ReDim OldValue(1 To Target.Areas.Count)
        
        For a = 1 To Target.Areas.Count
            NewValue(a) = Target.Areas(a).Value2
        Next
        
        Application.Undo
        For a = 1 To Target.Areas.Count
            OldValue(a) = Target.Areas(a).Value2
        Next
        Application.Undo ' restores original state
        
        ' For each non-contiguous range
        For a = 1 To UBound(NewValue)
            n = 0
            On Error Resume Next
               n = UBound(NewValue(a), 1)
            On Error GoTo EH
            Set TargetArea = rChanged.Areas(a).Cells
            If n = 0 Then
                ' Single Cell in Area
                UpdateCell TargetArea, OldValue(a), NewValue(a)
            Else
                ' Multiple Cells in Area
                For r = 1 To UBound(NewValue(a), 1)
                    For c = 1 To UBound(NewValue(a), 2)
                        UpdateCell TargetArea.Cells(r, c), OldValue(a)(r, c), NewValue(a)(r, c)
                    Next
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Private Sub UpdateCell(ByVal cl As Range, OldValue As Variant, NewValue As Variant)
    ' Update rules, in priority order
    ' 1.  NewValue is Blank - delete contents (leave cell as it is)
    ' 2.  NewValue contains commas - loop each value
    ' 3.  OldValue contains NewValue - remove it
    ' 4.  Else, Add NewValue to OldValue
    
    Dim OldValues() As String
    Dim NewValues() As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    If NewValue = vbNullString Then
        '1. do nothing
    Else
        '   Account for possibility user doesnt include a space after the comma, or includes several spaces
        Do While NewValue Like "*, *"
            NewValue = Replace$(NewValue, ", ", ",")
        Loop
        Do While OldValue Like "*, *"
            OldValue = Replace$(OldValue, ", ", ",")
        Loop
        
        OldValues = Split(OldValue, ",")
        NewValues = Split(NewValue, ",")
        If LBound(NewValues) < UBound(NewValues) Then
            ' Multiple NewValue
            For i = LBound(NewValues) To UBound(NewValues)
                '2. Loop for each NewValue
                UpdateCell cl, OldValue, NewValues(i)
            Next
        Else
            ' Single NewValue
            For i = LBound(OldValues) To UBound(OldValues)
                If OldValues(i) = NewValue Then
                    ' 3. remove it
                    OldValues(i) = vbNullString
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If i > UBound(OldValues) Then
                ' 4. Wasn't found, add it
                ReDim Preserve OldValues(LBound(OldValues) To UBound(OldValues) + 1)
                OldValues(UBound(OldValues)) = NewValue
            End If
            ' Rebuild Value
            OldValue = Application.TextJoin(",", True, OldValues)

            ' Alternative if TextJoin isnt available
'            OldValue = Join(OldValues, ",")
'            Do While OldValue Like "*,,*"
'                OldValue = Replace$(OldValue, ",,", ",")
'            Loop
'            If OldValue Like ",*" Then OldValue = Mid$(OldValue, 2)
'            If OldValue Like "*," Then OldValue = Left$(OldValue, Len(OldValue) - 1)
            

            ' restore spaces after commas
            cl.Value2 = Replace$(OldValue, ",", ", ")
        End If
    End If
    

End Sub
```

Comment: This is above and beyond and worked exactly as you've stated. I'm new here, is there a way to give something more than a +1. Cheers.